# Find $a$ if $\lim_{x\to-2}⁡\frac{3x^2+ax+a+3}{x^2+x-2}$ exists.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is there a number $a$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to-2}⁡\frac{3x^2+ax+a+3}{x^2+x-2}$$

exists? If so, find the value of $a$

I desperately need help in trying to work this out. I already tried out factorising the numerator to get an expression of $(x+2)$ to cancel the denominator's $x+2$ but so far no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $p(x)=3x^2+ax+a+3$ and $q(x)=x^2+x-2=(x-1)(x+2).$ Then we have:

$$p(-2)=15-a.$$

Case 1: $a \ne 15.$ Then $ \lim_{x \to -2}p(x) \ne 0,$ and $ \lim_{x \to -2} q(x)=0.$

Hence the limit in question does not exist.

Case 2: $a=15$. Then $ \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}= \frac{3(x+1)}{(x-1)} \to -1$ as $x \to -2.$

Comment: Can you explain why we need to make sure $a \neq 15$?  I factored the denominator, then I divided the numerator by the factor $x + 2$ and the algebra seems to cancel all $a$ and I got the limit to be $-1$.  So I (incorrectly) concluded that all reals $a$ would work.

Comment: I found my mistake.  I miss in all the answers here words that describe the strategy itself.  I had to go back to theory to sort of understand all the answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so we have $x^2+x-2=(x+2)(x-1)$ and $-2+2=0$ so we need the numerator to have an $x+2$ in its factorization. Call the numerator $P(x)$, now if theres an $x+2$ in its factorization then we know $P(x)=R(x)(x+2)$ where $R(x)$ is a degree 1 polynomial(this is by the polynomial dividing algorithm), which means $P(-2)=0$ so we have $P(-2)=12-2a+a+3=15-a=0$ so $a=15$. We have $3x^2+15x+18=3(x+3)(x+2)$. So the limit is $\frac 3 {-3}=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

We want $x=-2$ to be a root of $3x^2+ax+a+3$, hence $a=15$.

Comment: I'm not so sure what the strategy is.  We don't want the denominator to go to zero, right?  But if the numerator goes to zero, then we cannot be sure if the limit would exist.  So I think we're looking for non-zero numerator with zero denominator and also zero-numerator and zero-denominator --- although we won't know.  Would you answer these questions in your answer?  I would appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I finally understand.  If $a$ is not $15$, the numerator doesn't go to zero, but the numerator does, so it explodes up or down --- without a limit.  If it is zero, then *perhaps* we would find a limit, but we must check.  When we check, we find it's $-1$.  Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**.  If the limit exists, then that means $x$ approaching $-2$ doesn't make the function grow or decay without a bound.  If the numerator is a nonzero constant but the denominator goes to zero, then clearly the limit doesn't exist.  The denominator goes to zero when $x$ goes to $-2$.  What about the numerator?  It makes the function blow up if the numerator is not zero, too.  So our only chance at having a limit is when the numerator goes to zero, too.  When does it?  Only when $a = 15$.  And what happens when $a = 15$?  The numerator has a factor of $x + 2$ --- and another ---, so the numerator is factorable, it cancels the $x + 2$ and the limit turns out to be $-1$.  So $a = 15$ is the answer.

**Why another answer**?  All the answers here show the computations, but leave out the main thing, which is the theory for the solution.  This answer doesn't quite do the computation and shows the strategy and the insight necessary in a solution.  (The theory is taken for granted, but when one asks the question, surely it's a beginner we're dealing with.)

Comment: And the key words here in my opinion are polynomial long division.

Answer (score 1):

By [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division#:%7E:text=In%20algebra%2C%20polynomial%20long%20division,division%20problem%20into%20smaller%20ones.),
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to-2}⁡\frac{3x^2+ax+a+3}{x^2+x-2}&=\lim_{x\to-2}⁡\left(\frac{3x+a-6}{x-1}+⁡\frac{15-a}{(x+2)(x-1)}\right)\\
&=\frac{12-a}{3}+\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{15-a}{(x+2)(x-1)}
\end{align}$$
It is now clear that the limit exists iff $a=15$ and in this case the limit is $\frac{12-15}{3}=-1$.